# Where Can I Get The Latest GApps (Google services framework)?

Tags: google-apps

I need the latest version of GApps for my rom (running Android 4.1.2), however none of the sites that I found allow me to download it (I think it is an issue with my internet).

What is the best place to get them from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most frequently used site for downloading Google's proprietary bits is [Goo.im](http://goo.im/gapps) (formerly goo-inside.me).
However it can be a little confusing as it list all version so I recommend you check out [this](http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps) Rootzwiki page as it list the recommended versions as well as the changelogs.

Comment: Dead link! You should update it with the amount of page views/upvotes. Thx

Comment: Hey @AaronGillion, I'm no longer and android users, so I'm not up to date with this kind of stuff. I've made this into a community wiki, feel free to update it ;)